# connect aws redis using endpoints nodejs and get data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have AWS redis which stores some data. I want to get the stored data using the Redis endpoint URL and nodejs. Below are my code and response which I am getting.

code:

```
let client = require('redis').createClient('redis://abcbsamv:6379', {no_ready_check: true});
res.send(client)
```

response from the above code:

```
   {
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 1,
    "address": "endpoints:6379",
    "connection_options": {
    "port": 6379,
    "host": "endpoints",
    "family": 4
    },
    "connection_id": 0,
    "connected": false,
    "ready": false,
    "should_buffer": false,
    "max_attempts": 0,
    "command_queue": [],
    "offline_queue": [],
    "pipeline_queue": [],
    "connect_timeout": 3600000,
    "enable_offline_queue": true,
    "retry_max_delay": null,
    "retry_timer": null,
    "retry_totaltime": 0,
    "retry_delay": 200,
    "retry_backoff": 1.7,
    "attempts": 1,
    "pub_sub_mode": 0,
    "subscription_set": {},
    "monitoring": false,
    "message_buffers": false,
    "closing": false,
    "server_info": {},
    "old_state": null,
    "fire_strings": true,
    "pipeline": false,
    "sub_commands_left": 0,
    "times_connected": 0,
    "buffers": false,
    "options": {
    "port": "6379"
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you got the solution to connect to Redis cluster using Nodejs? I am facing the same issue in connecting Elasticache using nodejs.